# Name variable according to Function input in R

Tags: r, function, read.table

I am trying to perform the following:

```
Analyse_Store <- function("x"){
 datapaste"x" <- read.table(file = "x".txt, sep=";", header = TRUE)
    }
```

So basically I am trying to read a table named "x" and assign it to the name datapaste"x" unfortunately this does not work as expected and I cannot find any help online.
Thanks in advance

Comment: That `function("x")` isn't valid R. Is that an argument named `x`?

Comment: Read it into a list. See gregor's answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for a discussion and tips.

Comment: Yup - you really should read into a list instead. I won't downvote the current answers since they aren't "wrong".  But they're wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `assign` to read table into the variable named `x`.

The following function will take argument `x` and assign `x.txt` from working directory to a variable `x` inside the function.

```
Analyse_Store <- function(x){
        assign(paste("datapaste",x,sep=""), read.table(file = paste(x,".txt",sep=""), sep=";", header = TRUE))
}
```

Usage would be

```
datapastex = Analyse_Store("x")
```

Unless you are further processing the table inside the function, I don't see much use for a function in this case. You could just do

```
datapastex = read.table(file = "x.txt", sep=";", header = TRUE)
```